# php mysql - search a row and concatenate values of every columns to variable string

Tags: php, mysql, concatenation, multiple-columns

Hello friends need some help I am trying to get the following result:

```
$Steps= "1010"; TEXT
```

the above format from a mysql table

```
id    | step1| step2| step3| step4|
0001  | 1    | 0    | 1    | 0    |
0002  | 0    | 0    | 0    | 0    |
```

php:

```
$Nperm = 0;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($datos)){
        $result .= "$row[$Nperm]";
        $Nperm++;
    }
return $result
```

**can anyone help me with this I find nothing in internet**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take column names from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` and then loop them to concatenate each value column for the final string.

```
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_NAME', 'your_database');
define('DB_USER', 'your_user');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'your_password');

$link = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

$sql = "
    SELECT COLUMN_NAME
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE table_name = 'table_name' AND table_schema = 'your_db' AND COLUMN_NAME != 'id'
    ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

$columns = array();
$temp = array();

foreach($result as $row) {  //Take all column names
    $columns[] = $row['COLUMN_NAME'];
}

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($datos)) {
    $s = '';
    for($i = 0; $i < count($columns); $i++) {
        $s .= $row[$columns[$i]];
    }
    $temp[] = $s;   //Put all strings in an array
    echo $s.'<br />';
}
```

Comment: Do you mean that they have various names and not step1, step2, step3 etc?

Comment: yea it can take dinamicaly a table... need to get table colum and row by a id provide of 5 zerofill int variable... get the value of every columns and concatenate it on a php variable . and thank for your help

Comment: Please, keep the original question in the original state and post a new question.

Comment: ok i have a variable on php with this format: $variable = "000001000000" , I need to get characters at specific positions, for example, position 2 or position 6, and save it in another variable $variable2 = "0" variable3="1" I found to do it ranges, but not an exact position.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PHP implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php):

> implode — Join array elements with a string

So, just get every element of the result

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = '$id'`

Remove the ID item and `implode` the rest:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($datos)){
    unset($row["id"]);
    $result = implode($row);
    //do whatever with result
}
```

Comment: and tge second issues ?

Comment: Can't understand your second issue. Can you explain it again?

Comment: ok i have a variable on php with this format: $variable = "000001000000" , I need to get characters at specific positions, for example, position 2 or position 6, and save it in another variable $variable2 = "0" variable3="1" I found to do it ranges, but not an exact position.

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez In your example , `$variable2 = $variable[1];` , in general you can access the `n` element of an string by `$string[n-1]`.